# How to collect tweets from several months ago by using R?

Tags: r, api, tweets

Currently, I am trying to collect tweets by using the rtweet package in R. However, the rtweet package only covers tweets up to 7 days before.
I know some of the other website used to support this problem, but I'm not sure if collecting tweets from several months ago is still available.

Would anyone help me with this problem?